# Como cargar media a partir de un ArrayBuffer en Angular?

Tags: angular

estoy haciendo una aplicacion en la que llega un dato el cual puede contener un elemento de audio, video o foto, pero el archivo llega como ArrayBuffer, ya que segun investige si lo pongo como base64 pierde calidad. Entonces de esta forma tengo mi codigo :

```
this.socket.on('siguientePregunta', (data) => {

  switch(data.multimedia){
    case "image":
      const Iblob = new Blob([data.file], { type: 'image/*' });
      data.file = URL.createObjectURL(Iblob)
      break;
    case "audio":
      const Ablob = new Blob([data.file], { type: 'audio/*' });
      data.file = URL.createObjectURL(Ablob)
      break;
    case "video":
      const Vblob = new Blob([data.file], { type: 'video/*' });
      data.file = URL.createObjectURL(Vblob)
      break;
  }

   this.pregunta = data
 }
```

Como puedes notar recibo mis datos y eso llega bien, dentro de esa data hay una variable que determina el tipo de archivo(video, audio o foto) y pues dependiendo el tipo creo la URL del objeto y finalmente lo mando a la variable `this.pregunta` la cual es la que se usara en el html el cual es el siguiente:

```
  <div class="audio" *ngIf="pregunta.multimedia == 'audio'">
      <audio controls>
        <source [src]="pregunta?.file" type="audio/*">
      </audio>
  </div>
  <div class="video" *ngIf="pregunta.multimedia == 'video'">
      <video controls width="400" height="300"></video>
  </div>
  <div class="image" *ngIf="pregunta.multimedia == 'image'">
      <img [src]="pregunta?.file" alt="" type="image/*">
  </div>
```

Y pesar de eso no funciona, te dejo una imagen de referencia sobre como esta compuesto ese arraybuffer por si me estoy pasando algo:

[image: data array]

La primer solucion que ense fue tratar los reroductores con ElementREf y mandar directa,ente el contenido, entonces hice la siguiente prueba para los elementos de video:

```
playVideo(arrayBuffer: ArrayBuffer) {
  const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: 'video/*' });
  const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const videoPlayer = this.videoPlayerRef.nativeElement;
  videoPlayer.src = blobUrl;
  videoPlayer.play();
}
```

Pero tampoco funciono, y la verdad no eh pensado en mas estoy atascado.
Muchas gracias por leer

Comment: Me podrías indicar dónde viste que convertir algo a base64 reduce la **calidad**?? base64 es una representación de cualquier otra cosa, pero en formato texto. Como representación, los datos originales no se tocan. El principal problema de base64 es que al transformar por ejemplo un archivo (imagen o lo que sea) a base64 su tamaño se incrementa de media alrededor de 34% (lo probé hace tiempo ya y con pdfs) Si cambiar algo a base64 afectase a la "calidad" que pasaría cuando pasamos un pdf a base64?? Cambiaría el contenido!! Sería inaceptable y no sería una representación para nada del original.